# Generating gif with Wand independently of filename extension

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

Is there a way to force Wand to save image in the `.gif` animated format, no matter what is passed as `filename` to `Image.save()`?

```
with Image() as gif:
    gif.sequence = frames  # 10 images
    gif.format = 'gif'
    gif.save(filename='image.jpg')
```

This code creates 10 numerated jpg-s but I expected it to create a single file (`image.jpg` which is acutally a gif). The [documentation](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.format) says that the desired format can be set in the `format` field.

Why the extension in `filename` gets a higher priority than `Image.format`?

The version of Wand in question is 0.5.8.

UPD: Just to clarify, the discrepancy in my question is intentional. I'm interested in the case where `.format` is set to "gif" but the filename in `.save()` is passed with the incorrect extension ".jpg", and I'm wondering if there is a way to produce a single gif in this case. If the filename extension is set to ".gif", everything works fine.

Comment: What version of Wand?

Comment: I originally misread your question thinking your output was gif and getting multiple images. I see now you have used a suffix of .jpg. The output file will actually be a GIF animation regardless of suffix, if you preface the filename with GIF: as `gif.save(filename='GIF:image.jpg')` as pointed out to me by Eric McConville. However, I would really not recommend that as some tools only use the suffix to decide what format the file would be. So they will give an error when trying to read the GIF animation as a JPG.

Comment: Write a GIF and rename it *"incorrectly"* as a JPEG afterwards with `os.rename()` if you are really intent on playing "silly monkeys".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me with Wand 0.5.7 and Imagemagick 6.9.10.91 Q16 Mac OSX

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='desktop5_anim.gif') as img:
    img.format = 'gif'
    img.save(filename='desktop5_anim2.gif')
```

This also works to create an animation.

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='lena.jpg') as imgA:
    with Image(filename='zelda1.jpg') as imgB:
        imgA.sequence.append(imgB)
        for frame in imgA.sequence:
            frame.delay = 50
    imgA.loop = 0
    imgA.format = 'gif'
    imgA.save(filename='lena_zelda_anim.gif')
```

If you intent to keep the '.jpg' suffix in the filename, the output file will actually be a GIF animation regardless of suffix, if you preface the filename with GIF: as `gif.save(filename='GIF:image.jpg')`. However, I would really not recommend that as some tools only use the suffix to decide what format the file would be. So they will give an error when trying to read the GIF animation as a JPG.

(Thanks to Eric McConville for the pointers on how to add the delay and on the GIF: preface).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The discrepancy in my question is intentional. I'm interested in the case where the format is set to "gif" but the filename in `.save()` is passed with the **incorrect** extension ".jpg". I didn't expect the file extension to overload the `.format` field and I'm wondering if there is a way to produce a single gif in the case where the extension of the provided filename is incorrect. (if the filename extension is set to ".gif", everything works fine)

Comment: The solution that you mentioned in the comments (with `filename='GIF:image.jpg'`) looks like one way to do it, could you possibly elaborate on it?

Comment: Python Wand is based upon Imagemagick. Imagemagick identifies files by an argument in the header rather than the suffix, unless the format does not support keeping that information in the header. To tell Imagemagick what to put in the header and how to store the data to be consistent with the desired format, it uses the prefix: syntax. So saying you want GIF:image.jpg will telll Imagemagick to create a GIF file with GIF in the header as the flag, but write the file suffix as JPG. Any tool that uses the format flag from the header all read it as GIF.